# SUM and GROUP BY Using a Subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I been working on a question given to me to find the total room price of a hotel chain using a subquery and grouping them by Hotel. I currently have the following which seems to not work at all and get an error.

```
SELECT MAX(roomPrice) AS 'Total Room Price'
FROM room
WHERE IN  
(SELECT roomPrice, SUM(roomPrice) AS 'TotalRoomCost' FROM room GROUP BY hotel);
```

Any help would be appreciated

[Screenshot of the Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgfx7.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix is to select from the sub query.

I think from your description you want to sum all the room prices for each hotel, and the get the max total room price from all the individual hotels. If so something like this:-

```
SELECT MAX(TotalRoomCost ) AS 'Total Room Price'
FROM   
(
SELECT hotel, SUM(roomPrice) AS TotalRoomCost FROM room GROUP BY hotel
) sub0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change column names as these are not shown in attached screenshot.

```
SELECT
    H.Name AS HotelName,
    SUM(R.roomPrice) AS 'Total Room Price'
FROM room AS R
INNER JOIN hotel AS H
ON R.HotelID=H.HotelID
GROUP BY H.Name
```

Comment: It has to be done as a subquery as stated in the original question not by a inner join.